# Get audio frequency python ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, frequency

I need to get audio frequency from a flac file and save it in a variable.

I know the ffmpeg approach allowing to display info about the file:

`print(os.system('ffmpeg -i '+ file_path + ' -hide_banner'))`

The result looks like this:

```
  Duration: 00:00:11.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 134 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 16000 Hz, mono, s16
```

So the output shows the frequency, but what would be a good method to retrieve only the value of 16000 to save it in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

*(Landed here because of the same question I wanted to ask)*
Giving an alternative solution that I found since none of the answers had been accepted -- do not use `ffmpeg`, use `ffprobe` instead like this:

`ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -show_format -print_format json input.mp3`

Here is a sample output:

```json
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mp3",
            "codec_long_name": "MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/14112000",
            "start_pts": 324870,
            "start_time": "0.023021",
            "duration_ts": 3531499776,
            "duration": "250.248000",
            "bit_rate": "256000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "encoder": "Lavc58.13"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "input.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.023021",
        "duration": "250.248000",
        "size": "8008749",
        "bit_rate": "256025",
        "probe_score": 51,
        "tags": {
            "encoder": "Lavf58.76.100"
        }
    }
}
```

Use python (or any tools) to parse the returned json and get the `sample_rate` field.

Here is how to do it on CLI using the `jp` package:

jp - command-line interface to JMESPath

> The jp command is a command-line interface to JMESPath, an expression
> language for manipulating JSON (as XPath is to XML).
> https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

```bash
$ ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -show_format -print_format json input.mp3 | jp -u 'streams[0].sample_rate'
48000
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `pydub`:

```py
>>> from pydub import AudioSegment
>>> song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
>>> song.frame_rate
48000
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pydub. It is useful, The AudioSegment did not work for .flac files, but it was a good hint. I will post my approach inspired by your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
from pydub.utils import mediainfo

inf = mediainfo(file_path)
print(inf['sample_rate'])
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).